# Tree k length, fewer nodes

Tags: path, tree, depth-first-search, shortest

How to find What is the minimum number of nodes in path with weight **k** in *tree*? N,K<=2e5

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Talk us through a bit more about the problem you're trying to solve. What kind of tree are you working with? What is the "weight" of a path in a tree? What have you tried so far, and where specifically are you getting stuck?

Comment: Uff, it is like have connection from a to b with c cost

Comment: Please [edit] and add all essential information. [mre] would be best. Personally I can't understand the questions from the little info given,

Comment: We have n villages, they are connected with n-1 roads, there is only one path from each x and y. The president organize a parade. The parade is k kilometers. Each road can be used one time. He wants to know what is the minimum number of villages he have to use.